Stacking FILTERXML and WEBSERVICE formulas into one
I would highly appreciate if someone who is more experienced with the FILTERXML and WEBSERVICE formulas in EXCEL tell me if I am doing something wrong or the problem is in the web page I am trying to pull the data from.
The goal of the formula is to pull the last dividend data for Microsoft from Yahoo Finances. In this case that will be "0.75 Dividend". Here is the formula I am using that instead of the correct information it returns #VALUE.
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?filter=div");"/html/body/div[1]/main/section/section/section/article/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
PS: Unfortunately, I cannot use the in-build excel stock data as in it there is no information regarding the dividends.

WEBSERVICE => #VALUE! if the returned data is >32,767 characters. I suggest you use VBA and/or one of the free API's to obtain your dividend data. In your case, the returned data is >1,000,000 characters.

I understand. Thank you deeply for the reply. I was hoping to avoid VBA but I will look into potential solutions integrating an API call.
